# How to add hover text using another column excel

Tags: excel, plot

I would like to add hover text of another column value in a bar graph as shown below. What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Column contain the text you want above your bar graph and then Format Data Labels->Value From Cells.[Data Labels Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmiGt.png)

You could also use some VBA to do this also.

```
Sub editDataLabels()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(1).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(1).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertAfter "Text1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I only have Format Data Labels, but not Value From Cells..

Comment: What version of excel are you running?

Comment: It says version 16.28. Am I looking at the right information?